# Set Session Metasploit

Tags: exploit, metasploit, kali-linux

Metasploit exploits (exploits/windows/local/virtual_box_opengl_escape in specific) have an option called Session. What is this is to be set to? I am running Kali on virtual box on a Windows machine

Comment: Its a privilege escalation exploit which means you need to have a session on the target machine already established. You will then set the SESSION datastore option to the session ID you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a VM escape exploit. You use it to get a shell you have in a VM to break out of the guest machine into the host machine.

If you look at the [source code of the exploit](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/exploits/windows/local/virtual_box_opengl_escape.rb) it sais

```
'SessionTypes' => ['meterpreter'],
```

So that means you should give it the ID number of the meterpreter session you have.

You can see them with the command `sessions -l`